# I need all the possible combination from a max of each column

Tags: c#, binary, max, combinations

I'm coding an application in C# that is going to test all the possible combination of products.

To do so, I got the max from each product like :

```
List<string> maxEachProduit = new List<string> { "2", "3" };
```

and from that I want to get this output

```
*"00"
"01"
"02"
"03"
"10"
"11"
"12"
"13"
"20"
"21"
"22"
"23"
```

But, for example, from

```
List<string> maxEachProduit = new List<string> { "2", "1", "1" };
```

I would get this

```
"000"
"001"
"010"
"011"
"100"
"101"
"110"
"111"
"200"
"201"
"210"
"211"
```

I already got a function that create an binary list according to the length a want but that doesn't go to the max of each column.

The function looks like this :

```
private List<string> GetBinarySet (int length)
{
    List<string> res = new List<string>();

    int totalCombinations = (int)Math.Pow(2, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCombinations; i++)
    {
        string binary = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(length, '0');
        res.Add(binary);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I would reconsider the use of string to represent numerical data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused with the binary variables when there are other values not representing a 0 or 1. I'm going to assume you are not after actual binary (0,1) values but are looking for the all the possibilities of a given list of strings you can use recursion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class HelloWorld
{
        public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> numbers = new List<string>(){ "1", "2", "3" };
        var combinations = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            GetCombinations(numbers, i, combinations, new List<string>());
        }

        foreach (var combination in combinations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", combination));
        }
    }

    static void GetCombinations(List<string> list, int length, List<List<string>> result, List<string> current, int startIdx = 0)
    {
        if (current.Count == length)
        {
            result.Add(new List<string>(current));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = startIdx; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            current.Add(list[i]);
            GetCombinations(list, length, result, current, i + 1);
            current.RemoveAt(current.Count - 1); 
        }
    }
}
```